# How to use `warning()` in an Reference Class method?

Tags: r, oop, warnings, reference-class

`warning()` seems to be ignored in reference class methods, although `stop()` seems to work. That is,

```
TestA <- setRefClass("TestA", 
                methods = list(
                    warnMe = function() warning("Warn!!!"),
                    stopMe = function() stop("Stop!!!")
                )
            )
obj <- TestA()

obj$warnMe()
obj$stopMe()
```

yields only:

```
Error in obj$stopMe() : Stop!!!
```

Is this intentional and if so, why? How am I supposed to raise warnings inside class methods?

Comment: obj$warnMe() works for me. R 3.0.2, Windows 64bit.

Comment: Ahh, I think it might be my IDE - I'm using Revolution-R

Comment: make sure warnings are turned on? `options(warn=1)`.

Comment: Ahh, yes that did the trick -- my bad. I don't know how it got switched off though - I've never touched this option... You can post this as the solution and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure warnings are turned on `options(warn=1)`. –  Matthew Plourde